# Figuring out which experiment is being performed from the results of the experiment

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, measurement, density-matrix, quantum-state

Consider two different experiments involving qubits. In Experiment 1, a qubit is prepared in the mixed state $I/2$, where $I$ is the $2 × 2$ identity matrix. Alice then chooses an
orthonormal basis $B$ and performs the corresponding basic measurement on the qubit.
After Alice’s measurement, the qubit undergoes a unitary transformation $U$. After the
unitary transformation, Alice again performs the basic measurement corresponding to the
orthonormal basis $B$. Alice can repeat the experiment many times. Each time the experiment is repeated, a new qubit is used, again initialised in the mixed state $I/2$ . The unitary
transformation $U$ is fixed, meaning that it is the same each time Experiment 1 is run, but
on different runs, Alice can vary her choice of the orthonormal basis $B$.

In Experiment 2, two qubits are prepared in a joint pure state $|ψ⟩$. Alice then chooses
an orthonormal basis $B$ in the Hilbert space for a single qubit, and performs the corresponding basic measurement simultaneously on each of the two qubits. Alice can repeat
the experiment many times. Each time the experiment is repeated, a new pair of qubits is
used, again initialised in the joint pure state $|ψ>$. The joint pure state $|ψ>$ is fixed, meaning
that it is the same each time Experiment 2 is run, but on different runs of Experiment 2,
Alice can vary her choice of the orthonormal basis $B$.
You know that Alice has performed many runs of the experiment, and that either she was
doing Experiment 1 every time, or she was doing Experiment 2 every time, but you don’t
know which. You also don’t know the unitary transformation $U$, or the state $|ψ⟩$.

In each of the following cases, consider the further information, and state whether Alice
was performing Experiment 1 or Experiment 2, or whether it could have been either.
In each case, if it could have been Experiment 1 then give an explicit transformation $U$
that would give the observed data, and if it could have been Experiment 2, then give an
explicit state $|ψ⟩$ that would give the observed data. In each case, if it could not have been
Experiment 1 then give a proof, and if it could not have been Experiment 2, then give a
proof

- Alice always chose B = ${|0⟩, |1⟩}$. Every time the experiment was run, the outcomes
  of the two measurements were opposite.
- On some runs of the experiment, Alice chose $B = {|0⟩, |1⟩}$, and on other runs she
  chose $B = {|+⟩, |−⟩}$. With either choice, each time the experiment was run, the
  outcomes of the two measurements were the same.
- On some runs of the experiment, Alice chose $B = {|0⟩, |1⟩}$, on some runs she chose
  $B = {|+⟩, |−⟩}$, and on other runs she chose $B = {| + i⟩, | − i⟩}$. For any of these choices, each time the experiment was run, the outcomes of the two
  measurements were opposite.

$| + i⟩$ is defined as $(|0⟩ + i|1⟩)/\sqrt2$ and $| - i⟩$ is defined as $(|0⟩ - i|1⟩)/\sqrt2$

My attempt:

For the first one, second experiment, $|\phi⟩ = |0⟩⊗|1⟩$ seems to work.

First experiment: density matrix is either $((1,0),(0,0))$ after the first measurement, or $((0,0),(0,1))$ (as we're in one of the computational basis states after the measurement, with probability = 1).

Assume we're in $((1,0),(0,0))$, we need to find a $U$ such that $U((1,0),(0,0)) = ((0,0),(0,1))$

(ie in the opposite state with probability 1). It's easy to show that no such $U$ exists.

For the second problem, first experiment, after the first measurement the density matrix is in a state corresponding to only one of the vectors in the ONB we measured (with probability 1). Hence measuring on the same ONB guarantees that we get the same result if we use unitary matrix $U = I$.

Experiment 2: Let the basis chosen be $|\alpha_0⟩,|\alpha_1⟩$.

We require $|(⟨\alpha_i|⊗⟨\alpha_i|)|\phi⟩|^2 = 1$ for either $i=0$ or $i=1$

$\implies$ possible iff $|\phi⟩ = |\alpha_i⟩⊗|\alpha_i⟩$

but we have 2 possible ONBs to choose from hence this isn't possible.

Problem 3, experiment 1 should already be impossible from the first problem. I'm not sure about the second experiment.

Comment: First case, first experiment - "we need to find a U such that U((1,0),(0,0))=((0,0),(0,1))"  - this would be an X gate, no?

Comment: Oops i missed that - you're right